# Returned list in for loop

Tags: java

Can we use a returned value of a function in for-loop?

```
List<String> f();

for (String s: f()) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

During this loop there is no explicit reference to the list returned - doesn't GC delete it?

Comment: There is, you just don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by f() is referenced in the foor loop but not inside it. It's not created in each for loop and only this objects which get created in each iteration get collected by the garbage collector.